# Como puedo almacenar varios valores String en una variable en C#

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Tengo que crear una solución en C#, donde yo debo de ingresar un día de la semana y la consola nos diga si es un día laboral, o fin de semana. Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
using System;

namespace Tarea_1

{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Char diaSemana = [["Lunes","Martes",["Miercoles"],["Jueves"],["Viernes"]];
            Char dia;
            Console.WriteLine("Escriba el dia de la semana aqui: ");
             dia = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (dia == diaSemana){
                Console.WriteLine("Hoy es dia de la semana, es dia laboral.");
            }else{ 
                Console.WriteLine("Es fin de semana, descanza");
            };
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Creo que deberías de cambiar el `==` por **`Equals`** para comparar string y utilizar `ToLower` para que coincidan los caracteres, asi  `if (dia.ToLower().equals(diaSemana.ToLower()))` y tienes que recorrer el array que estas declarando `diaSemana`

Comment: @Jacob puede ser conviertiendo a json

Comment: @Jacob ¿Cuál es el problema concreto que encuentras? ¿Recibes algún fallo en alguna línea en concreto al compilar o ejecutar el código? No termina de quedar claro cuál es el problema de la pregunta y el título no se termina de corresponder con el contenido en sí (el título habla de variables String, la pregunta es sobre días de la semana, ¿es por la variable `diaSemana`?). Completa el [tour] y edita la pregunta para clarificar algunos puntos (y con ello ganarás una nueva medalla). Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Como puedo almacenar varios valores String en una variable en C#

Debes usar un arreglo de objetos de tipo `string`, de ese modo, podrás almacenar varios objetos (de tipo `string`) en un objeto.

Si usas la clase [Char](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char?view=netframework-4.8), no lo podrás hacer, debido que al momento de instanciar esta clase solo permitirá almacenar un caracter en el objeto.

Entonces, el código quedaría así:

```
string[] diaSemana = new string[5] 
{
    "Lunes",
    "Martes",
    "Miercoles",
    "Jueves",
    "Viernes"
};
```

El algoritmo para poder detectar si el día es laboral o fin de semana, sería:

- Pedir al usuario que ingrese el nombre del día.
- Verificar si ese día es laboral (para poder realizar esto, necesitaremos un bucle for para la comprobación).
- Luego, hay que comprobar si el día es sábado o domingo (con esto verificas si es fin de semana).
- Por último, si las dos condiciones de arriba no se cumplen, quiere decir que el usuario ingresó un día incorrecto.

Código implementando:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Byte diaCorrecto = 0;
        //Arreglo de objetos de tipo STRING
        string[] diaSemana = new string[5] 
        {
            "Lunes",
            "Martes",
            "Miercoles",
            "Jueves",
            "Viernes",
        };

        string dia;
        //Pedimos el dia de la semana
        Console.WriteLine("Escriba el dia de la semana aqui: ");
        dia = Console.ReadLine();
        //Recorremos cada objeto por separado para saber si es dia laboral
        for(int i = 0; i != diaSemana.Length; ++i)
        {
            //Si el dia ingresado por el usuario, es dia laboral...
            if(dia == diaSemana[i])
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hoy es dia de la semana, es dia laboral.");
                diaCorrecto = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(diaCorrecto != 1)
        {
            if(dia == "Sabado" || dia == "Domingo")
                Console.WriteLine("Es fin de semana, descanza");
            else 
                Console.Write("Has ingresado un dia de la semana incorrecto");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

La bandera `diaCorrecto` nos servirá para saber si el día ingresado por el usuario es válido, esto quiere decir, que cuando esta condición se cumpla:

```
if(dia == diaSemana[i])
```

La bandera `diaCorrecto` valdrá 1, esto significa que el día ingresado por el usuario si es válido, por lo tanto, las demás condiciones no necesitan ejecutarse; sin embargo, si la condición llegara dar como resultado un `false`, entonces este bloque de código se ejecutaría:

```
if(dia == "Sabado" || dia == "Domingo")
    Console.WriteLine("Es fin de semana, descanza");
else 
    Console.Write("Has ingresado un dia de la semana incorrecto");
```

Y pasaríamos a detectar si el día ingresado por el usuario es fin de semana, si no lo llega ser, es porqué el día es incorrecto.

También hay que tomar en cuenta que el operador de igualdad `==` es sobrecargado (para más información [String.Equality](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.op_equality?view=netframework-4.8)) por la clase `String` y que implícitamente, llama a [String.Equals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Equals_System_String_System_String_).

En pocas palabras, este código:

```
if(dia == diaSemana[i])
```

El compilador lo transforma a:

```
if(String.Equality(dia, diaSemana[i]))
```

El método `Equality` llama a [Equals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Equals_System_String_System_String_). El problema de hacerlo de esta forma es que cuando el usuario ingrese por teclado `LUNES`, le mandará un mensaje de error diciendo: `Has ingresado un dia de la semana incorrecto`. Para evitar este inconveniente, podrías hacer uso [String.Compare](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=netframework-4.8).

Con los cambios hechos:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Byte diaCorrecto = 0;
        string[] diaSemana = new string[5] 
        {
            "Lunes",
            "Martes",
            "Miercoles",
            "Jueves",
            "Viernes",
        };

        string dia;
        Console.WriteLine("Escriba el dia de la semana aqui: ");
        dia = Console.ReadLine();
        for(int i = 0; i != diaSemana.Length; ++i)
        {
            if(String.Compare(dia, diaSemana[i], true) == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hoy es dia de la semana, es dia laboral.");
                diaCorrecto = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(diaCorrecto != 1)
        {
            if(String.Compare(dia, "Sabado", true) == 0 || String.Compare(dia, "Domingo", true) == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("Es fin de semana, descanza");
            else 
                Console.Write("Has ingresado un dia de la semana incorrecto");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Gran aporte hermano, lastima que para cuando lo ley ya habia entregado la tarea utilizando un switch, pero wow, gracias, hay alguna manera de que pueda como "recompezanrte" en la plataforma, como dando estrellas y asi? :D

Answer (score 0):

una forma simple (pero no la más segura) de resolverlo es cambiar:

```
Char diaSemana = [["Lu...
```

por

```
string diaSemana = "lunes martes miercoles jueves viernes";
```

y

```
if (dia == diaSemana){
```

por

```
if (diaSemanaToLower().Contains (dia.ToLower()){
```

Comment: No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'string' en 'char'

Comment: tenes que declarar la variable "dia" como string también